# Redirect user from website A to B with authencation MVC with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to redirect a Logon user from website A to B with straight authenticate by calling the `Login` method from controller. It always redirect to login page always return "false"
controller was called and signinstatus return as true also.

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    return Redirect("/Home/Index");
}
```

**Ajax from website A**

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:50289/Account/Login', // try to use Url Helper when possible
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'POST', // use Get for [HttpGet] action or POST for [HttpPost]
        data: { model: LoginViewModel, returnUrl: "http://localhost:50289/eLeave/index" },
        success: function (result) {
            if (result == true) {
                window.open("http://localhost:50289/eLeave/Index");
            } else {
                window.open("http://localhost:50289/eLeave/Index");

            }
        }
    });
```

**Controller from website B**

```
 [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }


      var user = UserManager.FindByName(model.UserName);
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                UserManager.ResetAccessFailedCount(user.Id);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                if (user !=null)
                {                      
                    UserManager.AccessFailed(user.Id);
                }

                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: ajax call never redirect to another page.

Comment: returnURL was the redirect link passdown from ajax to controller

Comment: as @PrasannaKumarJ said, you cant perform a redirect using ajax call. Do a page submit instead of ajax POST

Comment: i am calling from another website. on the same. i managed to redirect the website using another approach at the ajax call result. But now encountered new problem at after deploying at the server.Everything works fine at the local machine. i will close this.